# Is it bad to add JSON on HTML data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Since HTML `data` attribute allows adding any custom data, I wonder if it is a good idea to include a set of `JSON` list as a `data` attribute? Then, the corresponding `JSON` can be easily accessed by `JavaScript` events with `getAttribute("data-x")`.

In fact, my question is that: Is it standard, efficient, and reasonable to add a large set of data to an `HTML` attribute?

For example

```
<div data-x="A LARGE SET OF JSON DATA" id="x">
```

Or a large set of JSON data must be stored within `<script>` tag, and an `HTML` attribute is not a right place for a large set of data, even for `data` attribute.

Comment: You would be MUCH better off storing the data in a script tag. Storing it in a data-attribute, while technically possible, just seems like bad practice. Buf if you really wanted to, you could. HTML5 specifies no limit for attribute lengths. (You might have to encode it or something though.)

Comment: @GJK: That does depend on the use case: if the JSON object in question is a single global data object then you're probably right; if there are multiple similar objects, each associated with a particular DOM element, then that is exactly the sort of thing that data attributes are intended for, so using them wouldn't necessarily be bad practice at all (storing the whole thing as a string in a single attribute might be, of course, but there's also the option of storing individual properties in different data attributes).

Comment: @GJK I don't think it is considered bad practice storing huge data set in a data-attribute. The very reason for creating such a tag is meant for data storage.

Comment: @GJK Can you elaborate on why you think this is bad practice?

Comment: Looking back, I should have clarified that it entirely depends on your use case. If you're injecting data on page load it might be a good idea. But if you're using data attributes to maintain application state you might have state management problems. I personally would avoid putting large amounts of data in an attribute, but I would at least encourage people to think if that's a good place to put the data.

Comment: @GJK thanks. Do you think there's any performance advantages to placing the data directly in a `javascript` variable instead (ie: with inline script tags)?

Comment: I can't say one way or the other, but that seems like a bit of a micro-optimization to me. Javascript engines are so fast nowadays I can't imagine it being an issue is most cases. But as alway, only benchmarking could tell for sure.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of storing everything in the data attribute you could use an identifier to access the data.

So for example you could do this :

```
var myBigJsonObj = { 
                      data1 : { //lots of data}, 
                      data2 : { //lots of data}                   

                   };
```

and then you had some html like so :

```
<div data-dataId="data1" id="x">
```

You can use jquery to get the data now like so :

```
var dataId = $('#x').attr('data-dataId');

var myData = myBigJsonObj[dataId];
```

This is the best approach imho.

Comment: This is a really smart solution! Thank you. With 'myBigJsonObj["property"] = value;' content can be created and fetched dynamically

Comment: this might not always work. Especially when you want to set data from server side.

Comment: @theusguy on the server you could output a script tag with the data variable.

Answer (score 3):

Say you want to save the object `var dataObj = { foo: 'something', bar: 'something else' };` to an html data attribute.

Consider first stringifying the object such that we have
`var stringifiedDataObj = JSON.stringify(dataObj);`

Then you can use jQuery to set the stringifiedDataObj as the data attribute e.g. with the `jQuery.data()` API

Answer (score 2):

While there's nothing to stop you embedding a long string of JSON in a data attribute, arguably the more "correct" way of doing it would be to add one data attribute per property of the JSON data. eg:

Javascript:

```
var dataObj = { foo: 'something', bar: 'something else' }
```

HTML:

```
<div data-foo="something" data-bar="something else"></div>
```

This way each piece of data in the JSON object corresponds to a separate, independently-accessible piece of data attached to the DOM element.

Bear in mind that either way you'll need to escape the values you're inserting into the HTML - otherwise stray " characters will break your page.

Comment: I believe if you use `JSON.parse`, characters are escaped if necessary

Comment: hi, this is great idea!! can you please share `how do I achieve this format?` does the JSON deserializer append / or give you this format `data-foo="something" data-bar="something else"`

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can, and I have seen several sites do this, but another solution is to store your JSON in a `<script>` tag and put a reference to the script tag in the `data` attribute. This is a better solution than just storing the data as a JS object in an actual script if the data is rendered to the page server-side, but there are CSP restrictions on inline script tags, for example.

HTML

```
<div data-data-id="#MyScriptData" id="x"></div>

<script type="application/json" id="MyScriptData">
{
    "fruit": "apple",
    ...
}
</script>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var dataId = $("#x").data("data-id");
    var dataTag = $(dataId);
    var dataJson = dataTag.html(); // returns a string containing the JSON data
    var data = JSON.parse(dataJson);

    ...
});
```

Comment: Hello this is interesting how do I find all the `<li> list/or div` items with a certain data-car attribute value=Hybrid and just get those `div` or `li` items or Id's back

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Where your element will be the key, and the value at that key could be an object in which you store wanted data. Something like this (not tested though):

```js
(function(global) {

  const map = new Map();

  global.CustomData = {
    add(element, key, data) {
      if (!map.has(element)) {
        map.set(element, {});
      }

      map.get(element)[key] = data;

      return map.get(element);
    },

    get(element, key) {
      if (!map.has(element)) {
        return null;
      }

      if (key !== undefined) {
        return map.get(element)[key];
      }

      return map.get(element)
    },

    remove(element, key) {
      if (!map.has(element)) {
        return false;
      }

      delete map.get(element)[key];

      if (Object.keys(map.get(element)).length === 0) {
        map.delete(element);
      }

      return true;
    },

    clear(element) {

      if (!map.has(element)) {
        return false;
      }

      map.delete(element);

      return true;
    }
  }

})(window);
```